# FFT stride pattern formula

Tags: pattern-recognition, fast-fourier-transform

### Edit

I have found a solution and I posted it below. Thanks to everyone who tried to help!

#### Question

I have implemented the radix-2 DIT FFT algorithm but I could not find a formula to determine the strides of the butterfly operations based on the stage. Let me clarify the terminology:

#### Terminology

For $N=8$ , the first stage would be to rearrange the array with bit-reverse order and then keep going with the "butterfly" stage which is the repeated pattern that you can see with 2 inputs and two outputs. We are not really interested in the operation itself here.

[image: fft overview]

As you can see at each stage the butterfly operation maintains its structure, but the **stride** and the **span** change.

[image: Stride and span]

#### Issue

My problem here is to find a formula that links the stride and the span at a given $n-th$ stage and the $b-th$ butterfly.

$$ stride( n, b) $$
$$ span  ( n, b) $$

I have found a formula for the span, which depends only on the stage $n$:

$$ span(n) =  floor \left( \frac{N}{ 2^{N-n}} \right) $$

But I can't figure out a formula for the stride.

#### My solution

At the moment my solution is to run a small algorithm to populate a vector with the starting indexes at each stage. The algorithm works by knowing the span and doing the same thing I'd do manually. The patterns are:

```
N = 8
      b = 0  1  2  3
Stage 0 > 0, 2 ,4 ,6
Stage 1 > 0, 1 ,4 ,5
Stage 2 > 0, 1 ,2 ,3
```

```
N = 16
      b = 0  1  2  3  4   5   6   7
Stage 0 > 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14
Stage 1 > 0, 1, 4, 5, 8,  9, 12, 13
Stage 2 > 0, 1, 2, 3, 8,  9, 10, 11
Stage 3 > 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,  5,  6,  7
```

Comment: Have you seen the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4052573/305862) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks! But that's more related to the algorithm itself, which I have understood, and my algorithm is working fine (I compare the results with numpy). I just wanted to know if there is a formula for those access patterns because I will move the algorithm to an fpga and it would simplify my source instead of hard coding the pre-calculated indexes.

Comment: Maybe you can find an answer in this on-line [handbook](https://doc.lagout.org/science/0_Computer%20Science/2_Algorithms/Handbook%20of%20Real-Time%20Fast%20Fourier%20Transforms_%20Algorithms%20to%20Product%20Testing%20%5BSmith%20%26%20Smith%201995-05-22%5D.pdf)

Comment: Have a look to this other very interesting textbook https://ivpl.northwestern.edu/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Digital-Signal-Processing-Handbook.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution. Borrowing the idea from [EEC 281 — VLSI Digital Signal Processing Notes on the RRI-FFT](https://www.ece.ucdavis.edu/%7Ebbaas/281/notes/Handout.fft3.RRI.pdf) , I noticed that the inner butterfly can be grouped together. It can be seen better from this image:

[image]

- First stage has $N/2$ groups , each with $1$ butterfly.
- Second stage has $N/4$ groups, each with $2$ butterflies.
- ...
- Last stage has $1$ group with $N/2$ butterflies.

Hence, my solution was to generate a function to keep track of

- *Number of butterflies per stage* $B(s)$
- *Number of groups per stage* $G(s)$
- *Stride of the group* $SG(s)$

Notice that $$G(s) * B(s) = \frac{N}{2}   , \forall   s$$

And use such functions for generating the access indexes.

Here's the code I wrote, in case anyone is interested:

```
def gen_idx(N):
    
    S = int(math.log2(N))
    
    B = lambda s : int(N/(2**(S-s)))
    G = lambda s : int(N/(2**(s+1)))
    
    SG = lambda s : 2*B(s)
    
    vec_idx = [0 for i in range(N//2)]
    idx     = 0
    
    for s in range(S):
               
        idx = 0
        
        for g in range( G(s) ):
            
            for b in range( B(s)  ):
                
                vec_idx[idx] = SG(s)*g + b
                idx += 1
                
        print( vec_idx )
```

Which outputs, for N = 16

```
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]
[0, 1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 11]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

But then we can merge the two inner loops into one, knowing that

$$
\begin{alignat*}{4}
g = floor \left( \frac{k}{B(s)} \right) \\
b = k \mod B(s) \\
k = 0 .. \frac{N}{2}
\end{alignat*}
$$

We can finally find the formula that we (I) were looking for:

$$ 
stride(s,k) = floor \left( \frac{k}{B(s)} \right) * SG(s) + k \mod B(s)
$$